# Wilcoxon signed-rank test with AUPRC

Tags: machine-learning, auc, precision-recall, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am a little confused about this topic. 

I computed mean AUPRC values using 5-fold cross validation for my classifier. I understand that comparing the mean AUPRC values for two classifiers to evaluate performance is not sufficient and should be accompanied by a p-value.
 Is it correct to use the n mean AUPRC values I collected for two classifiers on the Wilcoxon signed-rank test? Something like [0.987634, 0.943422,...] and [0.999332, 0.982321,...]? 
 Thanks!